# non-static variable cannot be referenced from static context [JAVA]

Tags: java, static, non-static

We have a school project where we are creating a text-based Black Jack game. I have created different classes like BlackJackDeck, Card, Hand, Player, and Dealer. My Teacher wants us to have a class called BlackJack were the game logic will be. I tried to make a main method inside BlackJack and added a reference to shuffle my BlackJackDeck deck. But it says that "non-static variable length leken cannot be referenced from a static context". If I don't have a main method my program won't be able to run. Here is my code:

```
package blackjack;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * @version 1.0
 * @author robert.englund
 */
public class BlackJack {

ArrayList<Spelare> spelare = new ArrayList<>(); //List with players
BlackJackKortlek leken = new BlackJackKortlek(4); //BlackJackDeck
Dealer dealer = new Dealer(); //The dealer

public static void main(String[] args) {

    leken.blanda(); //Shuffle deck

}


}
```

How should I do it so that I can make the game runnable so that I can write the game logic?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This will help you - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: Create a constructor for your BlackJack object which contains shuffle deck then add "new BlackJack();" inplace of where you have shuffle deck now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access a non-static variable from a static context.
Your variables(non-static) are outside of `main` method(static).
Declare your variables as below:

```
static ArrayList<Spelare> spelare = new ArrayList<>();
static BlackJackKortlek leken = new BlackJackKortlek(4);
static Dealer dealer = new Dealer();
```

Or declare it inside `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Spelare> spelare = new ArrayList<>(); //List with players
    BlackJackKortlek leken = new BlackJackKortlek(4); //BlackJackDeck
    Dealer dealer = new Dealer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate `BlackJackKortlek leken = new BlackJackKortlek(4);`

insinde of your `main()` method. After you have done that you can call the methods.

Answer (score 0):

you could simply declare leken as a static variable.

```
private static BlackJackKortlek leken = new BlackJackKortlek(4);
```

Also you should read on what the static keyword actually means.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access non-static variable `leken` inside a **static** method which you should not do, the reason being `instance variables` comes under picture only when you create the Object where as `static` method can be accessed without creating the object.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   leken.blanda(); // leken is non-static variable.
}
```

So, create the object inside the main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       BlackJackKortlek leken = new BlackJackKortlek(4); //BlackJackDeck
       leken.blanda(); // leken is non-static variable.
    }
```